# Sensor time distributions from arrays and cell arrays

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array and a numeric array in matlab which are inherently linked. The numeric array (A) contains a series of times from several data sources e.g. the time of each measurement. The array is n sensors (columns) by n measurements (rows). The array is filled with -1 by default since 0 is a valid time.

```
A = [ [ 100 110  -1  -1 ] ; ...
      [  -1 200 180  -1 ] ; ...
      [  -1 200 210 240 ] ; ...
      [ 400  -1  -1 450 ] ];
```

The cell contains the sensors, in chronological order, for each row of the numeric array. Each cell elements contains a vector showing the sensors in the order they made the measurements.

```
C = { [1 2] [3 2] [2 3 4] [1 4]};
```

I want to see the distribution of times relative to each sensor e.g. what is the distribution of times from sensor 2/3/4 (when they are present), relative to sensor?

For example...

Sensor 1 is involved in the first and fourth measurements and the other detectors were +10 (100 -> 110) and +50 (400 -> 450). In this case I'm looking to return an array such as [10 50].

Sensor 2 is involved in the first three events, one of which is a three-way event. In this case it sensor2 isn't always the first to trigger, so some values will be negative. In this case I'm looking to return [-10 -20 +10 +40)]

Using the same logic sensor3 should return [20 -10 30] and sensor4 [-40 -30 -50].

I'm sure there should be an easy way to do this but I can't get my head round it. Of course the example I've given is a very simple one.... normally I'm dealing with tens of sensors and 100,000's measurements so looping over each and every col / row will take a long time... and often draw little results if only two (or so) of the sensors trigger in each measurement. For this reason I was hoping to use the elements in the cell array to access only the correct elements in the numeric array.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So in the second row of `A` you have `[  -1 200 180  -1 ]`. In it,  does `200` correspond to the second sensor or the third sensor? Asking because the second cell of `C` is [3 2].

Comment: @Divakar: that's the second sensor (because it's in the second column)

Comment: @Divakar, the order in `C` represent the order of arrival. In [3 2] => third sensor triggered (@180), then sensor 2 (@200)

Comment: @Hoki -that's it, you've got it. The order is [3 2] because sensor3 triggered @ 180, 20 before sensor2 @ 200

Comment: Also curious if the order of output for each sensor is important? Like if I say `[-50 -40 -30]` instead of `[-40 -30 -50]` for sensor 4, would that be okay?

Comment: The output order can be either way round, as long as the input order is kept i.e. when looking at sensor1 the output times MUST be relative to sensor1, but the output could be [10 50] or [50 10]. The output array will eventually be histogrammed to show the time distribution i.e. number of occurrences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood the problem well enough for solving, it seems you don't need to worry about `C` for the output. Here's the code -

```
num_sensors = size(A,2)%// No. of sensors

A = A'; %//' The tracking goes row-wise, so transpose the input array
A(A==-1)=nan; %//set minus 1's to NaNs as excluding elements
out = cell(num_sensors,1);  %// storage for ouput
for k1 = 1:num_sensors

    %// Per sensor subtractions
    per_sensor_subt = bsxfun(@minus,A,A(k1,:)); 

    %// Set all elements of its own row to NaNs to exclude own subtractions
    per_sensor_subt(k1,:)=nan; 

    %// Get all the non-nans that correspond to the valid output
    out{k1} = per_sensor_subt(~isnan(per_sensor_subt));
end
```

Output -

```
>> celldisp(out)
out{1} =
    10
    50
out{2} =
   -10
   -20
    10
    40
out{3} =
    20
   -10
    30
out{4} =
   -40
   -30
   -50
```

---

As you have confirmed that the order of the output for each cell isn't important, you can employ a simplified approach that could be faster -

```
num_sensors = size(A,2)%// No. of sensors
A(A==-1)=nan; %//set minus 1's to NaNs as excluding elements
out = cell(num_sensors,1);  %// storage for ouput
for k1 = 1:num_sensors

    %// Per sensor subtractions
    per_sensor_subt = bsxfun(@minus,A,A(:,k1)); 

    %// Set all elements of its own row to NaNs to exclude own subtractions
    per_sensor_subt(:,k1)=nan; 

    %// Get all the non-nans that correspond to the valid output
    out{k1} = per_sensor_subt(~isnan(per_sensor_subt));
end
```

---

Fully vectorized solution if memory permits -

```
[m,n] = size(A)%// No. of sensors and measurements
A(A==-1)=nan; %//set minus 1's to NaNs as excluding elements

%// Per sensor subtractions
per_sensor_subt = bsxfun(@minus,A,permute(A,[1 3 2]))

%// Set all elements of its own row to NaNs to exclude own subtractions
own_idx = bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@plus,[1:m]',[0:n-1]*numel(A)),[0:n-1]*m);%//'
per_sensor_subt(own_idx)=nan;

%// Linear and row-col-dim3 indices of valid subtractions
idx = find(~isnan(per_sensor_subt))
[x,y,z] = ind2sub(size(per_sensor_subt),idx)

%// Get per sensor output
out = arrayfun(@(n) per_sensor_subt(idx(z==n)),1:n,'un',0)
```

---

If you would like to calculate `C`, use this approach -

```
%// Sort A row-wise
[sortedA,sorted_idx] = sort(A,2)

%// Set all invalid indices to zeros, so that later on we can use `nonzeros`
%// to extract out the valid indices
valid_sorted_idx = sorted_idx.*(sortedA~=-1)

%// Convert to a cell array
valid_sorted_idx_cell = mat2cell(valid_sorted_idx,ones(1,size(A,1)),size(A,2))

%// Extract the valid ones(nonzero indices) for the final output, C
C = cellfun(@(x) nonzeros(x), valid_sorted_idx_cell,'un',0)
```

Comment: +1. You beat me to it. I was just finishing a solution very similar (didn't transpose though, but why not. Why did you need to ?)

Comment: @Hoki Because the order would be different then. Asked a question on that as comment to OP on that. It gives me `[-50 -40 -30]` for sensor 4. Appreciate the +1! :)

Comment: Great solution! So basically the array contained in each element of the out cell is a list of the times relative to a specific sensor?

Comment: Also, as far as I can see the above two solutions are the same for everything except the tranpose and the row / col swap with k1 when excluding it's own row? Timing wise, I put both in a 10000 iteration loop and they come out about the same

Comment: @Mark That's right. But for each sensor the order of subtractions would be column-wise in the second approach and the vectorized solution as opposed to row-wise as adopted in the question. To know what I mean, run the second approach and see `celldisp(out)` for out{4} i.e. sensor 4 output.

Comment: @Mark Would be interesting to see the runtimes with the newly added vectorized approach too.

Comment: So I've run all three code examples in 10000 iteration for loops using my data examples for A and C, and weirdly the vectorised solution is the slowest! Elapsed time is 4.443178 seconds / 4.410831 seconds / 22.554514 seconds ( in the order posted)

Comment: @Mark Hmm, has to be the memory limitations and could be `arrayfun`

Comment: @Divakar are there any small modifications to this  code which could also give back an array or cell telling you which sensors triggered in each measurement and the order they triggered in? In essence, the equivalent of my 'C' cell above? If so I could remove a whole load of code I have to calculate a 'C' equivalent.

Comment: @Mark Sorry, I saw your comment when you posted, but somehow it missed me soon after. So here it is - `[v1,v2] = sort(A,2);C = cellfun(@(x) nonzeros(x), mat2cell(v2.*(v1~=-1),ones(1,size(A,1)),size(A,2)),'un',0);` Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks @Divakar! Works a treat but I'm not sure I understand what the cellfun part is doing...

Comment: Ah! I see now :-) I'll use the shorter version as it's probably quicker than generating unnecessary variables. Thanks for your help @Divakar